# Incorrect floating point aggregation

Tags: sas

I am working on a sas query below and getting weird exponential values in the summed up column:

```
    data t;
    input a b $ c $ d ;
    datalines;
    481710428888 24Nov2010 NP 34961.0000
    481710428888 07Mar2013 IP 175455.7500
    481710428888 09Nov2015 WB -63835.6400
    481710428888 23Nov2015 WO 27074.9000
    481710428888 23Nov2015 WO 49240.6500
    481710428888 23Nov2015 WO 70265.5600
    481910257067 01Apr2010 NP 47129.0000
    481910257067 27May2010 WO 47129.0000
    481910257067 22Mar2013 IP 3287.6900
    481910257067 11Apr2013 WO 3287.6900

    ;
    run;

    PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE WORK.IAP_VLTEST AS
    SELECT DISTINCT 
           put(a, z20.) AS ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
           b,
           c,
           d,
           (CASE WHEN c  = 'WO' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END) * d AS PRVN_A 
            ,SUM (CALCULATED PRVN_A) AS iap 
    FROM T
    GROUP BY 1
    ORDER BY a ;
    QUIT;

I get the following output
ACCOUNT_NUMBER              b        c      d          PRVN_A   iap
00000000481710428888    07Mar201    IP  175455.75   175455.75   7.27596E-12
00000000481710428888    09Nov201    WB  -63835.64   -63835.64   7.27596E-12
00000000481710428888    23Nov201    WO  27074.9     -27074.9    7.27596E-12
00000000481710428888    23Nov201    WO  49240.65    -49240.65   7.27596E-12
00000000481710428888    23Nov201    WO  70265.56    -70265.56   7.27596E-12
00000000481710428888    24Nov201    NP  34961        34961      7.27596E-12
00000000481910257067    01Apr201    NP  47129        47129      0
00000000481910257067    11Apr201    WO  3287.69     -3287.69    0
00000000481910257067    22Mar201    IP  3287.69      3287.69    0
00000000481910257067    27May201    WO  47129       -47129      0
```

I dont understand why am I getting this weird exponential value for the first value of a.
This is happening with several rows in my original dataset.
Could anyone please help understand what's going wrong here.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a very small sum `iap`.  Presuming all the `prvn_a` items in a group are a transactional group that should reconcile to zero, you are getting a very small non-zero result due to [Numerical Accuracy in SAS Software](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lrcon&docsetTarget=p0ji1unv6thm0dn1gp4t01a1u0g6.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en).  Numerical accuracy of decimal values is something that must be contended with in almost all programming languages.  There is nothing weird or erroneous going on.  I would recommend [rounding](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000245942.htm) the sum to the nearest 1e-5 in order to cover the four decimal places of data `d`.

```
, ROUND (
    SUM (CALCULATED PRVN_A), 0.00001
  ) AS iap
```